# Match full stop in a sentence using perl

Tags: regex, perl

how can I match full stop (period) in a sentence, but I don't want to match floating numbers or words that contain numbers?

eg.

```
$sen = "I'm going to match full.stop in sentence 3.142";
if ($sen =~ (s/\.//)) {
    print $1;
}
```

**output:**

```
fullstop
```

In this example I only want to match words or alphanumeric words not numbers.

Comment: Just to be clear: You want to delete the first period (the one in the middle of "full.stop"), but leave the second one (the one in 3.142) intact?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use look around :

```
$sen =~ s/(?<!\d)\.(?!\d)//g;
```

This will match a dot not preceded by a digit and not followed by a digit.

Updated according to OP's comment, this will remove dots that are followed by capital letter:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Modern::Perl;
use utf8;

while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    s/\.(?=(?:\s*[A-Z])|$)//g;
    # Or, if you want to be unicode compatible
    s/\pP(?=(?:\s*\p{Lu})|$)//g;
    say;
}

__DATA__
I'm going to match full.stop in sentence 3.142
I'm going to match full.Stop in sentence 3.142
I'm going to match full. Stop in sentence 3.142
I'm going to match full.stop in sentence 3.142. End of string.
```

**output:**

```
I'm going to match full.stop in sentence 3.142
I'm going to match fullStop in sentence 3.142
I'm going to match full Stop in sentence 3.142
I'm going to match full.stop in sentence 3.142 End of string
```

Comment: This was how I figured it too, except the OP said he didn't want to match "words that contain numbers", which makes it more complicated.

Comment: @M42 - thanks, what about if i want to match only those words that are followed by a capital letter?

Comment: @M42: I have a question in my question list, the question is: Matching words in a sentence using Perl? please can you give me your suggestion. thanks

Comment: @aliocee: The answer given by Borodin seems correct to me. Add comment to his answer if you see something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `/(\.(\D|$))|\D\./`. `\D` means non digit character, and `$` means end of the line

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete the first period (the one in the middle of "full.stop"), but leave the second one (the one in 3.142) intact, and also keep it in numbers such as "1." or "p.1223" you can do the following:

```
$sen =~ s/(\D)\.(\D)/$1$2/g;
print $sen;
```

Comment: Oof. Of course you're right; Forgot to remove the brackets after testing some other cases. Edited the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's nice to keep reg-exes as simple as you can, because they're already hard to read.

To match one or more not-digit-and-whitespace then the `'.'`, then again one or more not-digit-and-not-whitespace:

```
$sen = "I'm going to match full.stop in sentence 3.142";
print "$1\n" if $sen =~ /([^\d\s]+\.[^\d\s]+)/';
```

Gives:

`full.stop`

Comment: adding the output will make it a clear and complete answer. As you say yourself, regexes are not that easy to read so if you just give them like that it doesn't help much